# Undefined reference to gfortran_runtime_error

Tags: fortran, ubuntu-14.04, gfortran

I would like to run a model is written Fortran90 under Ubuntu 14.04. I use gfortran 95 compiler (gfortran 4:4.8.2-1ubuntu6). The required netCDF libraries (netCDF C and Fortran netCDF) are installed as suggested in: http://www.unidata.ucar.edu/software/netcdf/docs/. The netcdf is built as shared library so libnetcdf.so and libnetcff.so files there are in the library directory.  The libgfortran3 4.8.2-19ubuntu1 is installed for GNU fortran application linked against the shared library.
The LDFLAGS is set in the compiler_options.inc file by the following way:

```
INCDF=-I$(NCPATH)/include
LNCDF=-L$(NCPATH)/lib -lnetcdff -lnetcdf
LDFLAGS=$(INCDF) $(LNCDF)
```

When I compile the model I get the following messages:

```
/home/Beata/kid_a_setup/src/test_cases_2d.f90:1446: undefined reference to `_gfortran_runtime_error_at
```

Could someone explain me what causes the error and how I can fix it?

Answer (score 2):

undefined reference to `_gfortran_runtime_error_at` means that the libgfortran library has not been found.

Either your system is misconfigured (can you compile, link and run a "Hello, world" program using `gfortran`?), or you are using the `gcc` command for linking instead of `gfortran` for linking. `gcc` does not know about the libgfortran library, where _gfortran_runtime_error_at is defined.

Comment: I added static linking option to `LDFLAGS=$(INCDF) $(LNCDF) -static-libgfortran`. It solved the gfortran_runtime_error but I got the following errors: `In function main':
/home/Beata/kid_a_setup/src/KiD.f90:15: undefined reference to __main'`
`/home/Beata/kid_a_setup/src/common_physics.f90:141: undefined reference to ___chkstk_ms'`
`/home/Beata/kid_a_setup/src/diagnostics.f90:2311: undefined reference to __netcdf_MOD_nf90_strerror'` and more errors in connection with netCDF and chkstk_ms. Could someone write me how I can fix them?

Comment: Please show output from the "make" command which links the executable. It seems you are not including the right libraries, or are including them in the wrong order.  From the Makefile fragments that you have posted, it is impossible to tell.

Comment: `/bin/sh: 1: [[: not found
gfortran -g -O0 -W -Wall -pedantic-errors -fbounds-check -fbacktrace -ffpe-trap=invalid,zero,overflow -frange-check  -static-libgfortran    -o ../bin/KiD_SC_2D.exe ../obj/*.o   -I/home/beata/netcdf//include -L/home/beata/netcdf//lib -lnetcdff -lnetcdf   
../obj/KiD.o: In function main':
/home/Beata/kid_a_setup/src/KiD.f90:15: undefined reference to __main'`

Comment: This is strange. You get undefined references to ___chkstk_ms, which (as far as I can see) is a function that only crops up together with mingw. Are you sure you installed the libraries for the right architecture (Ubuntu)?  What do you get when you run the "file" command on the library files?